# How to add a property which is a lambda expression to a class created with TypeBuilder

Tags: c#, lambda, typebuilder

I am trying to define and create a class during runtime with the TypeBuilder. I'm getting along with normal properties etc. but what if i want to add a lambda expression to my class like this

```
Id(x => x.ID);
```

I'm using this as my example: [TypeBuilder.DefineConstructor Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dda9whaz%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

**Update:**

I think it's really an expression. Here is the code spoken of. You may recognize it as fluent mapping code.

```
public class AddressMap : ClassMap<Address>
{
    public AddressMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.NAME);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what your code is meant to be showing. What would you do if you were creating a normal class? (If you can show how you'd write the code as C#, we can show you how to construct the same type using TypeBuilder.)

Comment: Do you really mean an `Expression` or just a delegate?

Comment: No idea about what you said "add a lambda expression" to your class. What you've updated is to specify the property of an existing type. If you're just creating new types, how do you want to use lambda expression? I think something like `ID("MyProperty")` is sufficient.